# Рекурсия потока вывода

Tags: потоки-данных, бинарное-дерево, c++, перегрузка-операторов

есть некий класс

```
class set
{
public:
    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &out, set &ob);
private:
    struct setTree
    {
        int key;
        setTree *left;
        setTree *right;
    };
    setTree *ROOT;
};
```

подскажите как сделать рекурсию потока вывода при том что перегрузка вызывается попыткой вывести объект, а не структуру.

дерево выводится слева направо

Comment: ну что даже намекнуть никто не может?)

Comment: А что такое "рекурсия потока вывода"? Это очень странное сочетание слов. Может Вы попроще напишите, чего бы Вам хотелось?

Comment: если вы в курсе, то знаете что дерево поиска выводится на экран через рекурсию. примерно так:

void printLeftToRight(tnode *r)
{
 if(r!=NULL)
 {
  printLeftToRight(r->left);
  printf("%d(%d) ",r->key);
  printLeftToRight(r->right);
 }
}

так вот я хочу сделать вывод дерева через поток вывода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш `operator <<`, предназначенный для потокового вывода, принимает `const set&` как свой параметр, и, поскольку он объявлен **дружественным** к классу, то, соответственно, имеет доступ ко всем его внутренним полям.

*В таком случае одна из возможных реализаций могла бы выглядеть следующим образом:*

```
void PerformRecursiveOutput(std::ostream& out, const setTree& t) {
    if (t.left) PerformRecursiveOutput(out, *(t.left));
    // Или как угодно по-другому.
    out << t.key;
    if (t.right) PerformRecursiveOutput(out, *(t.right));
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const set& s) {
    if (s.root) PerformRecursiveOutput(out, *(s.root));
    return out;
}
```

---

Функцию `performRecursiveOutput`, кстати говоря, вполне можно оформить как `static` в соответствующем классе или заключить в `unnamed namespace` в файле с реализацией `operator <<`.

**P.S** `set` - не лучшее имя для бинарного дерева, особенно с учетом возможной коллизии с `std::set`. То же самое и относится к именованию структуры `setTree`, которой лучше бы подошло имя `treeNode`.